# Second Screen on Assassin's Creed 4

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

The game seems to have a second screen feature that allows you to do other stuff from an external device. I've been trying to find out more and found a few pages and videos that describe this companion app. However I can't actually find any solid details and it sounds quite fun and something I'd like to play with.

Can anybody tell me where I can find the App that I need or otherwise how I can make use of the second screen functionality?

**Edit**: Since somebody asked what exactly I meant the functionality that I believe it adds is just things like a map showing where you are and other useful information that you'd otherwise need to go into menus for. I believe there may be some options for offline minigames as well (ie offline for the main game, you'd have to be net connected for the app still). Also what I saw suggested that it was an apple and android app.

Comment: do you mean something like xbox smartglass?

Comment: I've seen this mentioned with regards to the Directors Cut of Deus Ex:HR recently too.  I found [this page](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/perceptual-screen-control.html) on the Intel website that mentions it, but there's no download link or anything at the moment.

Comment: @JLaBella: I've not used smarglass much but did load that up in case it did something special with AC4 plugged in but it didn't seem to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an iPad/Android app. from what I've read it was supposed to be released at the same time or shortly after the game.

In either case it's now available on the [Apple App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/assassins-creed-iv-black-flag/id692766233?mt=8) & [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ubisoft.assassin.blackflag) respectively.

Comment: I just looked at the Apple App Store and it's now available for download

Comment: i think it may be for the X-Box One/PS4, i've read about how the PS4 will support Second Screen functionality for tablets in certain titles, though i haven't updated my 360 in months and the last PS3 update (about 2 weeks ago) didn't say thing about a second screen

Comment: @Brian: Edit that comment into the answer (maybe with a link) and I'll accept your answer. For completeness add in the android link too: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ubisoft.assassin.blackflag . Sadly it tells me my device is not compatible but I suspect that is not true given how recent my device is. :( Not sure if my earlier searches just didn't find it or if it only just went up. I suspect the latter though.

Comment: @Chris - I've edited in the info for you, although in future you can always answer your own question if you've solved it and you feel the current answers are lacking.

Comment: @Chris: I thought about that but Brian's comment is actually what answered it for me so I Wanted to give him a chance to improve his answer before self-answering. If he hadn't I would have just answered myself.

Comment: It seems that the app is only compatible with Android tablets that are in the 10" screen size range.  All phones are incompatible.

Comment: Just a note with latest info that compatibility has improved massively and my S4 Active now runs it fine. Not sure of the full compatibility list though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link for the apple store version.

https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/assassins-creed-iv-black-flag/id692766233?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

Yes,The game has a application (App) that is downloadable from the App Store or the Google Play Store, the app is just a edited version of the pause screen of the console and PC versions. EG: Acessing Kenway's Fleet. It also records your position and other data in real-time.